# How to kill py::scoped_interpreter guard{} in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, python-embedding, pythoninterpreter

How to destroy python interpreter in pybind11 to call python function from c++ in loop

## Here am getting output for the first time ,when it's come for 2nd time loop it's throwing Microsoft C++ exception: pybind11::error_already_set at memory location 0x000000A21C2FFA10.

I know the problem, that is already created interpreter still alive but I'm trying to create a new interpreter in same memory location. But how to delete/clear/kill that already created interpreter and create new interpreter?

**C++ code(add.dll)**
`

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) double add(double a,double b)
{
        py::initialize_interpreter();
        {
             double  result= py::module::import("pyfile").attr("addition")(a,b).cast<double>();
cout<<result<<endl;
return result;
        }
         py::finalize_interpreter();
    }         
}
```

`
**pyfile.py (python code)**

def addition(a,b):
return a+b;

**c# code**

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("add.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern double add([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,SizeConst =16)] double a,double b);
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       double a=5.5;
       double b=3.5;
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
         double result= add(a,b);
         Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you need to destroy the interpreter after every loop iteration? Can't you modify the python script to have a single function you can call multiple times instead?

Comment: What's the actual payload of the `error_already_set` exception? ("payload contains a C++ string textual summary and the actual Python exception") Which exact statement throws this exception? What is `HRMSMLFunc`? Is it a binary module? A proper [mcve] wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Actully in need to create a c++ DLL and use it in c#.
user will give inputs from C# UI.Am taking those inputs to c++ with the help of dlland passing that inputs to python module through pybind11and retuning output to c# UI.

there will be inputs coming in loop from c#
It works fine for first time but for second time it crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution for this issue.I created a separate extern for creating and destroying

C++ code

```cpp
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void startInterpreter()    
    {
        py::initialize_interpreter();
    }
}
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) double add(double a,double b)
    {
        {
            double  result= py::module::import("pyfile").attr("addition")(a,b).cast<double>();
            cout<<result<<endl;
            return result;
        }
    }         
}
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void CloseInterpreter()
    {
        py::finalize_interpreter();
    }
}
```

Python file(pyfile.py)

```py
        def addition(a,b): 
            return a+b;
```

c# code

```cs
class Program
{
    
    [DllImport("add.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void startInterpreter();

    [DllImport("add.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern double add([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,SizeConst =16)] double a,double b);

    [DllImport("add.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void CloseInterpreter();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double a=5.5;
        double b=3.5;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
             double result= add(a,b);
             Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```